# Home broadband security logs

Tags: logging, router

I checked my home (broadband)routers security logs just today and found these logs

`LAN Attack: IN=ptm0.1 OUT=n/a MAC="mac address here"a SRC="source ip address here" DST="my public ip address here" LEN=129 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=115 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=15936 LEN=109 MARK=0x8000000`

and second log:

`Port Scan Attack: IN=ptm0.1 OUT=n/a MAC="mac address here"2 SRC="source ip address here"DST="my public ip address here" LEN=100 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 PROTO=UDP SPT=13291 DPT=54327 LEN=80 MARK=0x8000000`

These two logs have been appearing in my sec logs every day since June this year and there are already over 600 entries, probably .I can't view older logs

Can you explain what do these logs mean? Is this an actual attack? Can I prevent it?

Comment: It would help if you say what make and model of router you are using. Also, whether or not the source IP is your internal LAN or another public IP. That first source port looks like Bitorrent.

Comment: source addrress public ip 
router model zyxel f1000

Comment: Everyone freaks out when they first see their router logs. I see nothing here to be worried about.

Answer (score 1):

```
PROTO=UDP SPT=6881
```

TCP or UDP on port 6881 is usually associated with BitTorrent.  Most likely you (or a former user of your IP address) used BitTorrent for downloading something, and this is just a routine check to see if your computer is still part of the relevant BitTorrent swarm.  Nothing to worry about.

```
PROTO=UDP SPT=13291 DPT=54327
```

This could be anything.  Neither UDP port 13291 nor UDP port 54327 is associated with anything in particular; this could be backscatter, or a corrupted UDP packet, or leftovers from a VOIP session, or who-knows-what.  The one thing it probably *isn't* is a port scan: UDP port scans are slow, so an attacker will usually only scan ports that are likely to have something interesting on them.